# Tabulating dates with zero frequency on a data subset in R

Tags: r, date

I guess this is a rather easy problem: I want to count the frequency of occurences on a time line given some dates. The vector allDates, contains all dates I want to plot.

```
allDates <- structure(c(16193, 16194, 16195, 16196, 16197, 16198, 16199, 
16200, 16201, 16202, 16203, 16204, 16207, 16208, 16209, 16210, 
16211, 16212, 16214, 16215, 16216, 16217, 16218, 16219, 16221, 
16222, 16223, 16224, 16225, 16226, 16235, 16236, 16237, 16238, 
16268, 16270, 16271, 16272, 16273), class = "Date")
```

The frequencies of the vector dataSubset should be calculated.

```
dataSubset <- structure(c(16193, 16193, 16193, 16194, 16195, 16195, 16195, 
16195, 16195, 16195, 16195, 16196, 16196, 16196, 16196, 16196, 
16196, 16197, 16197, 16197, 16197, 16198, 16200, 16200, 16200, 
16200, 16200, 16200, 16201, 16202, 16202, 16202, 16202, 16202, 
16202, 16203, 16203, 16203, 16203, 16207, 16207, 16207, 16208, 
16208, 16208, 16208, 16208, 16208, 16208, 16208, 16208, 16209, 
16209, 16209, 16209, 16209, 16209, 16210, 16210, 16210, 16211, 
16211, 16211, 16211, 16211, 16211, 16211, 16211, 16211, 16211, 
16211, 16211, 16211, 16211, 16211, 16211, 16212, 16212, 16214, 
16214, 16214, 16214, 16214, 16215, 16215, 16215, 16215, 16216, 
16216, 16216, 16216, 16216, 16216, 16217, 16217, 16217, 16217, 
16217, 16217, 16217, 16217, 16218, 16218, 16218, 16218, 16218, 
16218, 16218, 16218, 16218, 16218, 16218, 16218, 16219, 16219, 
16219, 16219, 16221, 16221, 16222, 16223, 16223, 16223, 16223, 
16223, 16223, 16223, 16223, 16224, 16224, 16224, 16225, 16225, 
16225, 16226, 16235, 16235, 16235, 16235, 16235, 16236, 16236, 
16236, 16236, 16236, 16236, 16236, 16236, 16236, 16236, 16237, 
16237, 16237, 16237, 16237, 16237, 16237, 16238, 16238, 16238, 
16238, 16238, 16238, 16238, 16238, 16238, 16238, 16238, 16238, 
16270, 16270, 16270, 16271, 16271, 16271, 16271, 16272, 16273, 
16273, 16273, 16273, 16273), class = "Date")
```

If I simply use the table-function on a data subset, I get the frequency of all dates in the data subset.

```
table(datasubset)
```

However I would like to also include the dates where no event occured in the data subset. In other words I also want to include the zero frequencies of dates which are in allDates, but not in the dataSubset vector for which the frequencies are calculated.

Comment: `table(factor(dataSubset, levels = as.character(allDates)))`. Yet another dupe that I'm too lazy to look for...

Comment: Perhaps, this link would be close to duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705060/include-zero-frequencies-in-frequency-table-for-likert-data

Comment: Thanks, apparently I forgot to convert allDates to character...