# Include all factor combinations in contingency table to create square probability table/matrix

Tags: r, matrix, frequency, contingency

I am trying to create a 9 x 9 probability matrix from a contingency / frequency table.

It contains the frequencies for a pair of values `(x1,x2)` transitioning to a pair of values `(y1,y2)`. `x1` and `y1` have values of `A`, `B`, or `C`, and `x2` and `y2` have value of `D`, `E`, OR `F`.

Transitions between all `xy` pairs do not exist. However, I  would like to have these 'missing' transitions to be present as zeros with the table / matrix to make it square (9x9) for use in other analyses.

```
df <- structure(list(x1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
                    3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
                    y1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
                    2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
                    x2 = structure(c(1L,2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L), 
                    .Label = c("D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), 
                    y2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), 
                    .Label = c("D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), 
                    x = c("AD", "BE", "CF", "AD", "BD", "CD", "AE", "BE", "CE", "AE", "BF", "CD"), 
                    y = c("AD", "BE", "CF", "AE", "BD", "CD", "AD", "BD", "CD", "AE", "BE", "CF")),
                    .Names = c("x1", "y1", "x2", "y2", "x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")

# df$x <- paste0(df$x1, df$x2) # included in the dput
# df$y <- paste0(df$y1,df$y2)
# convert to factor to include all transitions http://stackoverflow.com/a/13705236/1670053
df$x <- factor(df$x, levels = c("AD", "AE", "AF", "BD", "BE", "BF", "CD", "CE", "CF"))
df$y <- factor(df$y,levels = c("AD", "AE", "AF", "BD", "BE", "BF", "CD", "CE", "CF") )

t1 <- with(df,(table(x,y)))
# t1m <- as.data.frame.matrix(t1)
t2 <- t1/(colSums(t1))
dfm <- as.data.frame.matrix(t2)
#dm <- as.matrix(dfm)
```

The result `DFM`, above, without using `factor` on `x` and `y` has the correct values, but of course does include the full set of 9x9 transitions. The desired results `DFMd` is below.

However, when I include the `factor`ed `x` and `y`, the result that is produced is not desired, values of `NA` and `Inf` are introduced.

Is there a way when using 'missing' factors to evaluate `table/colSums(table)` and get the desired result?

```
DFMd <- structure(list(AD = c(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AE = c(0.5, 
0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AF = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), BD = c(0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0), BE = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0), BF = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), CD = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0), CE = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), CF = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 
0.5)), .Names = c("AD", "AE", "AF", "BD", "BE", "BF", "CD", "CE", 
"CF"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("AD", "AE", "AF", 
"BD", "BE", "BF", "CD", "CE", "CF"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still unsure why the code above produces some `inf` value or the wrong values otherwise, but the code below results in the desired output. It does seem a bit convoluted.

```
t1 <- with(df,(table(x,y))) # contingency table
tcc <- as.matrix(colSums(t1)) # get col sums
tc <-as.data.frame.matrix(tcc) # store as data.frame to using the rep code below
tct <- t(tc) # transpose to build matrix of colsums
tcx <- tct[rep(seq_len(nrow(tct)), each=9),] # http://stackovernflow.com/a/11121463/1670053 build colsums dataframe to be 9x9

pmat <- t1/tcx # transition matrix
pmat[is.na(pmat)] <- 0 #remove na from 0/0
```